# Android development on OS X 10.7 (Lion)

Tags: android, macos, ide

I would like to start developing Android apps using my old Mac. It still runs the OS 10.5.8 (Leopard) but I can upgrade it to 10.7 (Lion). Unfortunately, it does not seem like it is possible to upgrade my Mac to 10.8 (Mountain Lion).
When I see the system requirements for the Android Studio, it looks like at least the OS 10.8 is required.

My question now is: can I use my Mac for Android development, or do I need to buy a new machine? In case I can, which version of Android Studio should I install and where can I find it?

Comment: The previous official IDE was Eclipse with ADT - see e.g. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html. Eclipse requires 10.5 or greater, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

No need to buy new macbook. You can use eclipse for your android development. http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html